# ASPxTextbox.Text is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a textbox named ASPxTextBox1 in a gridview's footer. I get the textbox in codebehind:

```
 var tbox = (DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxTextBox)grdCommunication.FindFooterCellTemplateControl(grdCommunication.Columns[3],"ASPxTextBox1");
```

The textbox is not null, so I have it in my hands. Still, tbox.Text is always empty (""). Any idea?

Here's the aspx, just in case:

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdCommunication" runat="server" DataSourceID="CommunicationSQLDataSource" Settings-ShowFooter="True"  OnRowInserting="grdCommunication_RowInserting"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="500px">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="Date" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UserName" VisibleIndex="2"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Message" VisibleIndex="3">
            <FooterTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="169px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Height="19px" Text="ASPxButton" Width="255px" CommandName="Insert" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click1"></dx:ASPxButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Settings ShowColumnHeaders="False"></Settings>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

The Page_Load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        }
        else
        {
            activeuserID = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        }

        pid = "05811de5-6345-4806-b489-154576c69e6d";
        CommunicationSQLDataSource.SelectParameters["ProjectID"].DefaultValue = pid;
        grdCommunication.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: try this TextBox tx = (TextBox)dataGridView1.FindFooterCell("ASPxTextBox1");

Comment: there is no such method in devexpress

Comment: Where is the binding of the grid being done, `Page_Load`? Please post the code where you are binding the grid.

Comment: Hi I've added it to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the value is getting lost because you're re-binding the grid on each page load, therefore invalidating the previous data. Try wrapping the DataBind statement in a Page.IsPostback check like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        grdCommunication.DataBind();
    }
}
```